# Как декодировать JSON такого вида?

Tags: swift

Есть JSON -

```
{
  "selectedValue  ": "1",
  "valuesByID  ": {
    "1": {
      "value  ": "1",
      "name": "test"
    },
    "2": {
      "value  ": "2",
      "name  ": "hello"
    },
    "keys  ": [
      "1",
      "2"
    ]
  },
  "isNeedToRefresh  ": false
}
```

Как можно его задекодить? Затык заключается в том, что я не знаю как добираться до полей, где имя может поменяться. В данном случае, есть поля 1 и 2. Но там может быть что-то и другое (3,4,5 и тд), но внутренность этого объекта будет такой же

Comment: один из вариантов использовать lodash _.forIn и складывать в массив с объектами но это мб костыльно

Comment: У вас тут есть объект keys, он содержит ключи других объектов с переменными именами или нет?